# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object (unable to solve despite research)

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select Un from member where Lock = ? and Activated = ?');
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", 'N', 'Y');//This line gave the error
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt->store_result();//apply to prepare statement
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows;

if ($numRows > 0)//if have result
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
```

my above code gave me a **"Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object"** error.
I really don't get it why i getting this error. I have correct cols name.

I am new to mysqli and would like to learn how to debug such error.

1. what is the problem with my prepare statement or bind_param()?
2. Please teach me how to debug such error

Comment: `bind_param()` expects variables passed by reference. You can't pass string literals by reference.

Answer (score 14):

`Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` means that `$stmt`, which you're trying to call `bind_param` *on*, is not an object. Why is it not an object? Because `$mysqli->prepare` did not return an object. Why did it not return an object?

> `mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or `FALSE` if an error occurred.
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

So that means an error must have occurred. You should turn on [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting), which will probably tell you, or examine [`$mysqli->error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), which may tell you as well.

Comment: Error turn on and it said "
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Lock = ? and Activated = ?'"

I still can't see why my sql is wrong.

Comment: @Jerry `Lock` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). Put your field names in backticks to avoid this ambiguity: `WHERE \`Lock\` = ...`

Comment: thanks =D
But now having another problem that "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference".
To what i know, it refer to "Y"?
What i done wrong now?

Comment: @Jerry The parameters need to be *variables*, not just text. If it's just unchanging static text you don't need to bind the values in the first place, you can just write them into your query as-is.

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", 'N', 'Y');//This line gave the error
```

Here you need to sure about data type in database.

Answer (score 0):

> `mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or `FALSE` if an error occurred.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-returnvalues).

`$mysqli->prepare()` may be returning `FALSE`. Write a condition to deal with that situation.