# Closing a connection in a loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
/* Get the 10 latest posts from users you're following */
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ?) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 15');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

/* If a result exists, continue. */
if ($result->num_rows) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        /* Get the user's username from their id */
        $stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $row['user_id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close(); // this is where I'm closing the connection
    }
}
```

In the third last line, you'll notice that I'm closing the connection in the while loop. The issue is that, if I remove that line, I get the error on that line.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

I'm guessing that closing the connection and then re-opening it again for the next element in the loop is not a good thing. So, how can I fix this? Why do I get this error when I remove the close connection line?

Comment: just move `$stmt->close();` outside `if`

Comment: In the second iteration of the loop it causes the problem you mentioned as obvious. Close the statement only after you finished with it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have a better query for this? Using joins perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

```
/* Get the 10 latest posts from users you're following */
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ?) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 15');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

/* If a result exists, continue. */
if ($result->num_rows) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    /* Get the user's username from their id */
    $stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id = ?');
    $userid = (int)$row['user_id'];
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $userid); // Forcing $row['user_id'] to int
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username);
    $stmt->fetch();
    //$stmt->close();  Don't close it here
  }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Another approach but little more time consuming is:

```
 /* Get the 10 latest posts from users you're following */
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ?) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 15');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

/* If a result exists, continue. */
if ($result->num_rows) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    /* Get the user's username from their id */
    $stmt_loop = $cxn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id = ?');
    $userid = (int)$row['user_id'];
    $stmt_loop->bind_param('i', $userid); // Forcing $row['user_id'] to int
    $stmt_loop->execute();
    $stmt_loop->bind_result($username);
    $stmt_loop->fetch();
    $stmt_loop->close();  //Close the local stmt here
  }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I've tried the first one you suggested, I still get the error. :/

Comment: did you remove `$stmt->close();` from inside the loop ?

Comment: Yes, I've removed it.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on line $stmt->bind_param('i', $row['user_id']);`

Comment: Have a read on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659882/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object-unable-to-solve-despite

Comment: I now get this error: `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference` on that same line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40475/discussion-between-deepak-and-burrows)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example i've got on one of my Github repositories which tackles this issue:

```
$Query = $Database->prepare("FIRST QUERY");
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($ID,$Password);
$Query->store_result();
   while ($Query->fetch()){

       $Secondary_Query = $Database->prepare("SECOND QUERY");
       $Secondary_Query->bind_param();
       $Secondary_Query->execute();
       $Secondary_Query->close();
   }
$Query->close();
```

Modify this to suit your working scenario, and you will have a successful running query